# Какой нужен веб-сервер для Go

Tags: golang

Вопрос обусловлен прочтением System requirements на https://golang.org/doc/install
В частности:
Debian GNU/kFreeBSD not supported
CentOS/RHEL 5.x not supported
Здесь же перечислены основные операционные системы для веб-серверов, они все не поддерживаются? Какую тогда ставить?

И ещё вопрос нужен ли какой-то сопутствующий софт? (для php например ставится nginx или apache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Работает GO на всех платформах.**
Но предварительно должен быть скомпилирован для необходимой платформы. Например можно в Windows скомпилировать код для работы в UNIX системах. Делается это с помощью переменных среды. Предпочтения отдают во многих случаях **Ubuntu** и **Centos** всегда лучше ставить свежие.

Если вы пишите свой сервер то Nginx не нужен. Но если вы хотите использовать роутер или балансировщик нагрузки то конечно Nginx поможет. Но надо помнить, что Nginx имеет свои прелести.

**База данных** - дело требований. Все зависит от поставленных задач и требований к скорости. Нужна самая высокая скорость это **Redis**, если нужен веб сервис - MongoDB или RethinkDB. Конечно никто не отменял и замечательные **MySQL** и **Postgree** если необходима реляционная база или например вы влюблены в триггеры и хранимые процедуры.

Answer (score 1):

Ставьте Ubuntu 16.04. В подарок получите GO 1.6 из коробки

Что касается дополнительного софта, то тут всё зависит от ваших пожеланий

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. Так на других ОС Go работает? В этом значительная часть вопроса на самом деле для меня? И что ещё желательно ставить для веб-сервера на Go?

Comment: Для web сервера не помешает nginx, и конечно же базы данных, если вы планируете их использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Таблицу по вашей ссылке следует понимать так:

Поддерживаются:

- Все релизы FreeBSD начиная с 8-й версии. Исключение [Debian GNU/kFreeBSD](https://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/)
- дистрибутивы GNU/Linux с ядром 2.6.23 и выше. CentOS 5-й ветки возможно уже очень древний, и видимо приведен как один из частоиспользуемых серверных дистрибутивов.
- С MacOS и виндой думаю понятно.

Из сопутствущего софта для разадчи статики можете так же использовать Nginx как и с PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Работает везде, для веб-сервера окружение настраивать не нужно, как на рабочем компьютере, надо лишь обеспечить запуск скомпилированных программ, например через systemd.

В качестве веб-сервера поставьте nginx (в настройках пропишите proxy_pass), сможете обращаться к своим Go веб-приложениям не по разным портам, а по одному порту (:80) и разным хостам.